# Json jwt token problem - TypeError: Object of type 'User' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, flask, jwt, access-token

Im trying to attach a token to a logged in user:

```
user_info = request.get_json()
entered_username = User.query.filter_by(username = user_info['username']).first()
        if user_info['password'] == entered_username.password:                                                                  
            token = jwt.encode({'username':entered_username, 'exp':datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)},
                               secret_key, algorithm='HS256').decode('UTF-8')
        return jsonify(token)
```

But i get: `TypeError: Object of type 'User' is not JSON serializable.`
I've also tried to do `return jsonify(token.decode('UTF-8'))`

What am i missing?

Comment: Just what is says: you can't encode a `User` object to JSON and `entered_username` is a `User` object. If you just want the username in your token, encode `{'username': user_info['username'], ...}`.

Comment: Do you mean the whole thing? I tried `{'username': user_info['username'], ...}.decode('UTF-8') but then i get  AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: Yes, the ellipsis meant the rest of your code, not literally a `...`. I'm also not sure why you're trying to call `decode` here.

Comment: No i meant the rest of the {} or the rest of the entire code. not ... haha. I get the same thing for encode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't encode a `User` object to JSON and `entered_username` is a `User` object. If you just want the username in your token, you can do something like this:

```
user_info = request.get_json()
user_obj = User.query.filter_by(username = user_info['username']).first()
if user_info['password'] == user_obj.password:
    claims = {
        'username': user_info['username'], # or perhaps user_obj.username
        'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
    }

    token = jwt.encode(claims, secret_key, algorithm='HS256')

    # Maybe some error checking here?

    response = {
        'token': token.decode()
    }

    return jsonify(response)
```